# PHP Function only returning one row when multiple should be returned

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote a PHP function to display the role name of a person when they log into my website. However when a user has multiple roles it only returns one row instead of all of them. Any help would be appreciated.

**getRoleName Function**

```
function getRoleName($conn, $id)
{
        $id = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $sql = "SELECT 
                * FROM users
                INNER JOIN user_roles ON users.usersId = user_roles.user_id
                INNER JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_id = roles.role_id 
                WHERE users.usersId = ?;";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        //$stmt -> mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        $stmt -> bind_param("s", $_SESSION['userid']);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows > 0){

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                if ($row['role_name'] == 0) {
                $array = array($row['role_name']);
                foreach ($array as $value) {
                        echo $value;
                }
                }else{
                echo "no role!";
                }//end else
            }//end while
        }else{
        echo "JPS Says go away from me!";
        }//end if numrows                       
}
```

The index.php file is where the role is being displayed for the user to see.

```
<?php 
include_once 'header.php';
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

?>
<?php  
if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) 
{
    echo "<p>Hello there " . $_SESSION["useruid"]. "</p>";
    echo "Your roles are ".getRoleName($conn, $_SESSION["userid"]);
}//end isset
    
                ?>
<?php 
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: If you want to return multiple rows, then you need to create an *array*, put the rows into the array, and return the array at the end of the loop.

Comment: In your `while` loop to fetch the data, you always return inside the loop.  But you also `echo` out the returned value - so this won't display an array either.

Comment: @NigelRen I thought it was bad form to echo in a function

Comment: Not always - but also that isn't what I was suggesting.  If you return an array, and echo -it will fail, so you would also need to modify that code as well.